# Export PDF as Landscape mode in MVC extension grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, export, page-size

I have implemented export functionality in MVC grid extension and its worked properly. Now I need export as PDF formate in landscape mode. I have tried

`GridViewExtension.WritePdfToResponse(ExportContractorViewSettings(), objreportentity, PdfExportOptions ????);`

method but I don't know how to use PdfExportOptions property for export pdf as Landscape mode.

My code is shown in below,

```
GridViewExtension.WritePdfToResponse(ExportContractorViewSettings(), objreportentity, PdfExportOptions ??????);
```